# After Uploading files using dropzone, The display looks off

Tags: dropzone.js

In dropzone.js, after I upload a single, or multiple files, it displays the success mark and the error mark, and looks really bad. Is there a way that I can make it similar to the try it out example on dropzone.js? ( a gray block with file size and filename)

Comment: Are you including dropzone.css?

Comment: No I didn't realize that dropzone had its own css. Thanks